# Extending a block from core:

Tags: blocks, overrides

For some odd reason this isn't being extended

The core block is called

```
class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract
```

and is located at:

```
magento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method/Available.php
```

I am extending it with:

```
class CompanyName_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available
```

located at:

```
local/Companyname/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method/Available.php
```

here is what my block config section currently looks like:

```
<blocks>
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
       <available>CompanyName_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available</available>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
</blocks>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `available` to `onepage_shipping_method_available` path to block

```
<blocks>
    <!-- ... -->
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <onepage_shipping_method_available>CompanyName_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available</onepage_shipping_method_available>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
</blocks>
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
<rewrite>
<onepage_shipping_method_available>....</onepage_shipping_method_available>
</rewrite>
```

or less but still possible:
CompanyName is camelCased except in directory name.. there were some issues with it in the past